# How can I build a SMPS? Why is there no transformer before the full bridge diode in a SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I am currently trying to build switch mode power supply for a future project. The problem is that I can't find a step-by-step process and how some components (capacitor, resistor, inductor) were calculated in the circuit.

I would be grateful if anyone could guide me to a book/video/notes/lecture/website.

Why is there no transformer before the full bridge rectifier in a SMPS like there is in a linear power supply?

Comment: A linear power supply needs a transformer before the bridge. A switching converter uses the transformer in a different place. Asking for recommendations for books etc.. is likely off-topic and makes you question problematic to answer until it is fixed-up.

Comment: SMPS chip datasheets usually tell how to calculate component values. And based on your second question, you seem to be specifically asking about a mains input switch mode power supply. The big mains transformer is the first component you need to get rid of due to size and inefficiency, simply by using unisolated rectified mains as DC input to switch mode transformer. But asking for recommendations about good books is off-topic, they are also opinion-based.

Comment: This can help you for some smps http://schmidt-walter-schaltnetzteile.de/smps_e/smps_e.html#Ivw

Comment: I recommend having a read of the classic [Horowitz and Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics).  Chapter 9.6 (3rd ed.) is all about switching regulators.

Comment: You can have a look at an introductory [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20SMPS%20Rev%200.32.pdf) that I recently posted on my webpage. It talks about switching conversion. If you want to design a switching converter, this is a vast topic and one way is to look at my [book](https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Mode-Power-Supplies-Second-Edition/dp/0071823468/ref=dp_ob_image_bk) on the subject which includes many design examples.